# keyCode 13 stops working after two clicks in Internet Explorer but works in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a JS function:

```
var dialog_open = false;
    $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            if(dialog_open == true){
                $( "#auth-error" ).dialog( "close");
                return;
            }
            $("#sign-in-button").click();
        }
    });
```

Essentially, this is working (it toggles between closing an open dialog box and clicking a sign-in button that triggers a click function). It works as described in Chrome, however, in IE 9 it stops working after the second 13 keyup (example: form loads, user presses enter, gets a dialog box, presses enter again, dialog box closes, presses enter again, nothing happens). Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: When you get to the step just after the dialog box closes, where is the focus? If you press `tab` or `shift-tab`, where does the focus go?

Comment: no specific focus (unless it's a specific error, then it focuses on a specific HTML element after the dialog box closes) ...

Comment: What I mean is where is the focus right after the box closes? In each browser? If you hit `shift-tab` and then `tab` in  Chrome, do you end up on the link? Is the same case present in IE9? If you're intentionally moving the focus, you may be in a situation where the browser can't see the event you're listening for if the focus leaves the page. If you click inside the page after the error behavior begins, does your `Enter` key listener start working again? More code will probably get you more help.

Comment: (Revised) Unable to duplicate problem in IE9.  The posted code only closes the dialog box.  Could there be a conflict with another keypress handler that is used to open the dialog?